# Mongoose with MongoDB Schema Validators

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

Mongoose has some validators built in, but it requires access to the document at the time of running the validation. Therefore, validating on fields that are `$inc` cannot happen, since you won't know the value that you're writing to the the document before it has been written.

So for e.g. if you had a field you decremented every-time something happens and you never wanted it to reach 0, you cannot just add a `min` rule on that field when you define your schema in Mongoose. See [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators-only-run-for-some-operations) example

MongoDB released [Schema Validators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) in 3.2. This does happen atomically, since the validation sits within the document fields themselves, I'm not completely sure how it works internally, I'm assuming MongoDB has these validators baked into the document like they do with `$types`.

Regardless, it solved my initial issue, I was decrementing fields and needed it to happen atomically to avoid any race conditions.

But now I sit with something like this in my source code:

```
MyCollectionSchema.on('index', function(error) {
  mongoose.connection.db.command({
    collMod: "MyCollection", 
    validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
        bsonType: "object",
        properties: {
          MyDecrementingField: {
            bsonType: "int",
            minimum: 0,
            description: "you cannot go below 0"
          },
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Essentially when mongoose has finished building my indexes I edit that collection and add my custom validators to it. But this introduces new issues to versioning and maintaining this. I tried searching for Mongoose Collection Validators or Mongoose MongoDB Validators but I can't find anything where Mongoose supports adding these validators to a collection. Maybe I'm blind and dumb, but this feature isn't that new and I was hoping Mongoose has some sort of built in support for it like they do with indexes.

Or Alternatively is there some sort of Mongoose feature I could use to version control theses changes? It's going to be tricky adding more of these validators down the line, since indexes aren't created every time I change my models and I don't want to modify every document each time the code runs.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution for this? I am working with mongoose and have a need to add the schema validations but can't find a way to do that using mongoose.